# auto resize charts to its parent div Ploty js

Tags: html, plotly

how to auto size plotly.js charts to its parent div width only without getting parent div overflow.

var data = [{
type: "pie",
values: [2, 3, 4, 4],
labels: ["Wages", "Operating expenses", "Cost of sales", "Insurance"],
textinfo: "label+percent",
textposition: "outside",
automargin: true
}]

var layout = {
autosize: true,
showlegend: true,
title: "Expence Status",
}

Plotly.newPlot('myChart1', data, layout)